# Set base URL in angularjs project based on the environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base-url

I'm working on an AngularJs project created using Yeoman. The project uses Grunt as task manager.

In my index.html I need to set the base url:

```
<base href="/">
```

The href attribute value depends on the environment: if the environment is development I want href to be simply `/`, if the environment is production the value has to be something else `a/b/c`.

What are the available solutions to this problem?

It is possible to set it dynamically at runtime using a constant from AngualrJs or it is better to set it statically at build/serve time?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I prefer to set it a build/serve time, so I don't need to change the code when I change environment.

So, I can push on the server and use `grunt serve:production` - you don't need to change the code, so you can use git hooks and a bash script to easily serve your code.

To achieve this in Grunt you can use [ngcostant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant). You define the vars you want, and it creates a file named config.js (or whatever you want) that exposes your vars under `ENV` (or whatever you want) using `.configure()`

Talking about your case, you can have something like this in your Gruntfile:

```
ngconstant: {
  options: {
    space: ' ',
    wrap: '"use strict";\n {%= __ngModule %}',
    name: 'config'
  },
  vagrant: {
    options: {
      dest: 'app/scripts/config.js'
    },
    constants: {
      ENV: {
        name: 'vagrant',
        baseUrl: 'http://192.168.33.99/api/v0',
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      dest: 'app/scripts/config.js'
    },
    constants: {
      ENV: {
        name: 'test',
        baseUrl: 'http://test.example.com/api/v0',
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Then, in your app you can take the baseUrl using `ENV.baseUrl` and expose to your html file, like this (angular):

```
app.run(function($rootScope, ENV.baseUrl){   
    $rootScope.baseUrl = config.baseUrl;
});
```

(html)

```
<base ng-href="{{baseUrl}}">
```

So you can serve your application using `grunt serve:vagrant` when you're using vagrant or `grunt serve:test` when you want to run on your test server

Comment: From Angular can you control the href attribute of the base tag and change it a runtime?

Comment: @Fedy2 of course, I updated the answser, let me know if there is something else unclear

Comment: Tried this solution but AngularJs says that base tag is missing. I'm wondering if the base tag is ready and bound to the baseUrl var value when AngularJS checks for base tag presence.

Comment: Maybe is better to post a separate question in SO.

Comment: @Fedy2 right, I forgot to specify you have to use app.run, let see if now it works :-)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately is not working. Inspecting the DOM I see set correctly but in the console there is an error about missing base url. I've open a dedicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049927/it-is-possible-to-set-the-href-attribute-of-base-tag-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Try with [grunt template package](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template):

> Template strings can be processed manually using the provided template
>   functions.

This package offers default delimiters ie. `<%= placeholder %>` to replace variable values in placeholder given a that you are using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Another package, [grunt-processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml) provides processes html with special comments:

```
<!-- build:<type>[:target] [inline] [value] -->
...
<!-- /build -->
```

Example on how to use with  in HTML file:

```
<!-- build:remove:staging,prod -->
  <base href="/app/public/" target="_blank" />
<!-- /build -->
```

And on production you could do the following:

```
<!-- build:[href] a/b/c -->
  <base href="/app/public/" target="_blank" />
<!-- /build -->

<!-- will be changed to -->
<base href="a/b/c/" target="_blank" />
```

Comment: I don't understand the first solution that you're proposing.

Comment: Thanks @Fedy2 , removed and updated with examples for <base> with grunt packages

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to not include any other dependencies at all (yeoman has enough already). I simply used the `blockReplacement` feature of `usemin` and added a `dev` target to my `build` task.

This allows me to use `grunt build` for production distribution, `grunt build:dev` for development distribution (remote) and `grunt serve` for normal local development.

In my `html`:

```
<!-- build:baseUrl /somepath/ -->
<base href="/">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

In my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
...

var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist',
    dev: false // added dev boolean at ~ line 22
};

...

assetsDirs: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
    ],

    // added blockReplacements at ~ line 250
    blockReplacements: {
        baseUrl: function (block) {
            if (appConfig.dev) {
                return ['<base href="', block.dest, '">'].join('');
            }
        }
    }

...

// Altered the default build task to accept a target
grunt.registerTask('build', 'Compile the code base for distribution', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dev') {
        appConfig.dev = true;
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:dist',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);
});
```