# It is possible to set the href attribute of a base tag in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, html5-history, base-url

I want to set the `href` attribute value of `base` tag based on a constant value. To do so I've declared the `base` attribute in the `head` element as follows:

```
<head>
  <base ng-href="{{baseUrl}}">
</head>
```

and I set the `baseUrl` value with this code snippet:

```
app.run(["$rootScope","env", function($rootScope, env){   
    $rootScope.baseUrl = env.baseUrl;
}]);
```

where `env` is the Angular constant.

The `locationProvider` is configured in this way:

```
.config(function ($locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

When I run it I see the value set correctly:

```
<base ng-href="/" href="/">
```

but in the console I get this error:

```
Error: [$location:nobase] $location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$location/nobase
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
    at $LocationProvider.$get (angular.js:11293)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4185)
    at angular.js:4003
    at getService (angular.js:4144)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4176)
    at angular.js:4003
    at getService (angular.js:4144)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4176)
    at angular.js:6485
```

If I set the href attribute directly without ngHref:

```
<base href="{{baseUrl}}">
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://items/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:9000'.
 at Error (native)
 at Browser.self.url (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5044:56)
 at setBrowserUrlWithFallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11313:18)
 at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11435:15
 at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14401:28)
 at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14217:31)
 at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14506:24)
 at bootstrapApply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1448:15)
 at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4185:17)
 at doBootstrap (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1446:14)
```

Where `items` is the default routing path:

```
 .otherwise({
    redirectTo: 'items'
  });
```

Comment: This could be because html5 location api. try putting *$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);* in your application **config** function.

Comment: I'm setting the html5Mode to true.

Comment: if you are using html5 location api instead angular hashbang(!#), no need to use *ng-href*, just use **href** in your **base** element.

Comment: Using href I get a different error, I've updated the question.

Comment: can you please replace *binding* with static value with **/**. i.e. ** <base href="/">**

Comment: Yes, no errors with the static value, but I need the dynamic value.

Comment: **base** element is not where you are supposed to set default root state/route for your angular apps. What is the *url* of your **items** route. That is where you'll set default root state.

Comment: I'm not setting the default route path in the base element. I need to set the base href property based on deployed environment.

Comment: But does it work when you set base href to 'http://localhost:9000'?

What about this solution [relative post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494954/how-do-i-set-a-pages-base-href-in-javascript)

Comment: Not sure what kind of servers or deployment process you have but if it were me, I'd probably use SSI (server side includes). Assuming that for each deployment environment you have a different http server configuration file.

Comment: What is in env.baseUrl?

Comment: I know this sounds stupid but I gotta ask... are you sure <base> is being managed by Angular? (i.e. you have a controller set above it)

Comment: Another thing, from the docs: "Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value" Is this your case? you cannot simply use href?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `base` href in JavaScript via `createElement`, then do manual bootstrapping:

```js
    /* Create base element */
    var base = document.createElement('base');
    /* Create script element */
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    /* Set base href */
    base.href = "http://example.com";
    /* Set script src */
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js";
    /* Append base tag to body */
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(base);
    /* Append script tag to head */
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    
    function html5Mode ($locationProvider) 
      {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      };

    function dothis()
      {
      //template string
      var html = "<div>ID: {{$id}} Phase: {{$$phase}} Destroyed: {{$$destroyed}} listeners: {{$$listeners}} root: {{$root}}</div>";
      //template object
      var template = angular.element(html);
      //template transformer
      var compiler = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$compile");
      //template result
      var linker = compiler(template);
      //scope object
      var scope = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$rootScope");
      //scope binding
      var result = linker(scope)[0];
    
      /* Append result to body */
      document.body.appendChild(result);
    
      /* Render */
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['ng', html5Mode]);
      }
    
    script.onload = dothis;
```

**References**

- [AngularJS Guide: Bootstrapping - Things to keep in mind](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#things-to-keep-in-mind)
- [AngularJS API: module ng](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng)