# How to setup AngularJS $locationProvider HTML5 mode for non-root base urls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I have a working AngularJS (1.3.8) application, which is deployed as a web app in Tomcat under an application context 'app'.

URLs look like this:

```
https://www.myserver.com/app/#/login 

https://www.myserver.com/app/#/register
```

etc. Routes are defined like this:

```
$routeProvider.when(
    'login',
    {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html?' + now, controller: 'LoginController'}
);

$routeProvider.when(
    'register',
    {templateUrl: 'partials/register.html?' + now, controller: 'RegistrationController'}
);

$routeProvider.otherwise(
    {redirectTo: 'login'}
);
```

Everything is working fine. What I now need to do is remove the hashbangs from the URLs and use the HTML5 mode of $location. So far, I can not get this to work.

My assumption was that I just need to call

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

and now the app URLs change to

```
https://www.myserver.com/app/login 

https://www.myserver.com/app/register
```

This is not working. When I request the URL

```
https://www.myserver.com/app
```

Angular redirects to

```
https://www.myserver.com/login
```

Overall, the whole routing and resource loading is broken with this change. For example, the partials URLs in the routing definitions can not be resolved. They are only working when I add a '/app/' prefix.

I tried to use the base tag, changing the $locationProvider call to

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true
});
```

and using

```
<base href="/app">
```

Surprisingly, this has no effect. Still, entering https://www.myserver.com/app leads to a AngularJS-redirect to https://www.myserver.com/login. The URL https://www.myserver.com/app/login is not available.

This is how I use the base tag:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <link href="css/mycss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    ...
    <script src="js/my.js"></script>
    <base href="/app">
</head>
<body class="ng-cloak">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

I also encounterd other problems. For example, if I change the location of the base tag inside the HTML file like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <base href="/app">
    <link href="css/mycss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    ...
    <script src="js/my.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="ng-cloak">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

then suddenly the JS and CSS files can not be resolved any more during load.

Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you must have trailing `/` inside base `href`

```
<base href="/app/">
```

Comment: Where do you set the base tag? Is this base tag supposed to set within the $locationProvider.html5Mode() method? Please provide an example of how and where this is supposed to be set.

Comment: base tag will appear in `head` tag & `$locationProvider.html5Mode() ` inside `app.config` phase

Comment: Pankaj, what if the production files lies under myserver/MyProject/ whereas during development MyProject will be your root folder, so in this scenario do we have to manually edit the index.html base href after deployment. Also the above solution does not work during development running on local server.

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari this can be taken care while creating build of your application, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30048945/2435473) basically you should place a placeholder on your index.html and then replace it from automation tool like grunt or gulp