# html5mode breaks AngularJS routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, angularjs-ng-route

I am having an issue with using `html5Mode` with ngRoute not quite like issues others have had with the same thing. Here is the most relevant section of my code:

```
(function () {
  var config = function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'common/views/genericText.view.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .when('/location/:locationId', {
        templateUrl: 'locationDetail/locationDetail.view.html',
        controller: 'locationDetailCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    /* $locationProvider.html5Mode({
     enabled: true,
     requireBase: false
    }); */
  };

  angular
    .module('loc8r', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', config]);
})();
```

The issue arises specifically with the route for `/location/:locationId`. With `html5Mode` on, an attempt to load a URI like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/location/5a27ab691c5e0a989c0634da` results in a blank page. Curiously, my logging output from Node tells me that the template and controller are both being accessed. Even more curiously, if I change the route from `/location/:locationId` to just `/:locationId` and load a URI like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/5a27ab691c5e0a989c0634da`, then the page will load. But the only way to get `/location/:locationId` to work is to leave `html5Mode` disabled and then go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/#!/location/5a27ab691c5e0a989c0634da`. But that's ugly. How can I get `html5Mode` working in this case?

If necessary, I can push all my most recent changes to GitHub and then provide the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set up `base` attribute in `index.html` file?

Check: [How to setup AngularJS $locationProvider HTML5 mode for non-root base urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424897/how-to-setup-angularjs-locationprovider-html5-mode-for-non-root-base-urls)

Comment: That fixed it. Weird.

Comment: That'll take a few minutes.